# I want to view my page link and is not coming

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

Please Someone should help me. Im using laravel 7 and i have set my controller and route but the page is not coming . I used `<a href="mision">">Mision & Vision</a>` as my nav link.

And for my controller, i used

```
public function mision() {
    return view('mision');
}
```

This is my route.

```
Route::get('/mision', 'PagesController@mision');
```

i also tried this route and never came.

```
Route::get('/mision', 'PagesController@mision');
```

After i execute or refresh my webpage
i get `404 Not Found`
Please what am i missing . any solution??

enter code here

Comment: `<a href="mision">">` looks like a typo. Also, use the helpers: `<a href="{{ url('/mision') }}">Mision &amp; Vision</a>`. (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#urls-method-list)

Comment: Call from the root, give a slash before the path `href="/mision"`

Answer (score 1):

You are linking the word 'mision' instead of the route, either:

Use URL:

```
<a href="{{ url('/mision') }}">Mision & Vision</a>
```

or name the route:

```
Route::get('/mision', 'PagesController@mision')->name('mision');
```

and use the route() function:

```
<a href="{{ route('mision') }}">Mision & Vision</a>
```

[URL function documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-url)

[Route function documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route)

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="{{url('mision')}}">">Mision & Vision</a>` use this instead of `<a href="mision">">Mision & Vision</a>`. The `url()` will generate absolute path.